# jquery: is there a fail handler for $.post in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, handler

When $.post succeeds, there is a success handler for it. What happens if it fails? Is there a similar handler that we can use for this case, so that we can inform the user that something is not happening right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not, according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), a specific error handler for `$.post` method.

What you have to do, if you want to have both the success and fail handlers, is to use the low-level `$.ajax` method. It's documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  success: function(html){
    /* Do success stuff here */
  },
  error: function(){
    /* do error stuff here */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch it using [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/), but this applies to all ajax requests in your application. You also need to make sure you send back a HTTP error status back to the front end to be captured by jQuery.